# Arrow function doesn't trigger inside a HTML

Tags: javascript, html, design-patterns

I've been working on a to do list for my web dev studies with The Odin Project. My assignment is to create a to-do app and I chose the composite design pattern to do after a lot of struggle with my previous messy code. So far so good but one of my button oddly doesn't trigger the arrow function I prepared for it. I said oddly cause I've got a very similar approach for another button the works perfectly. The only difference I feel it's causing this issue is an assignment to a button for the let's call it root of this tree structure (session.js class). document.getElementById effectively finds the specific button in the document and the addEventListener trigger a alert for example if there's no arrow function involved. Can anyone lend me a hand with this please?

The problem is in the addEventListener inside the if statement inside the addChild function of the following class

```
import Component from './component.js';

export default class Container extends Component{
  child;
  constructor(){
    super();
  }
  addChild(id, parentId){
    alert(id);
    alert(parentId);
    document.getElementById(parentId).appendChild(document.createElement('div')); 
    document.getElementById(parentId).lastChild.id = id;
    document.getElementById(parentId).lastChild.innerHTML = this.child.innerHTML;
    document.getElementById(parentId).lastChild.className = this.child.className;

    if(document.getElementById(id).className!='check-list'){
      document.getElementById(id).innerHTML+="<button id='"+id+"-add-button'></button>";
      document.getElementById(id+'-add-button').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
       this.child.addChild(this.parentNode.id);
      });
    }

    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML+="<button id='"+id+"-remove-button'></button>";

    document.getElementById(id+'-remove-button').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    document.getElementById(id).parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById(id)); 
    });    

    let inputs = document.getElementById(parentId).getElementsByClassName('input');
    for(let i=0; i<inputs.length; ++i){ 
     inputs[i].addEventListener('input', ()=>{
       inputs[i].dataset.storage = inputs[i].value;});
    }
  }
}
```

Container class inherits from Component class

```
export default class Component{
    className;
    innerHTML; 
  constructor(){
  }
}
```

And Session class is the only class that, if I can call it override in this case the same event

```
import Project from "./project.js";
import Container from "./container.js";

export default class Session extends Container{
  constructor(username){
    super();
    this.username = username;
    this.child = new Project();
    this.innerHTML = ["<div id='"+this.username+"-session' class='session' data-checklist='' data-card='' data-list='' data-project''>",
                "<H1>Call it a day!</H1>",
                "<button id='session-add-button'>Add Project</button>",
                "<button id='logout'>Log out</button>",
                "</div>"].join("");  
    document.body.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('session-add-button').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
      this.addChild(this.username+"-session");
    })
  }

  addChild(parentId){
    super.addChild(Project.getId(), parentId);
    ++Project.count;
  }
}
```

BTW Project class is Session class child so you guys can picture the whole flow in your minds

```
import Container from "./container";
import List from "./list";

export default class Project extends Container {
  static count=0;
  static getId(){
    return 'P-'+Project.count;
  }
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.child = new List();
    this.className = 'project';
    this.innerHTML = ["<input class='input' data-storage='' type='text' placeholder='Project title'></input>"].join("");
  }

  addChild(parentId){
    super.addChild(List.getId(), parentId);
    ++List.count;
  }
}
```

I've checked already if the button inside that if in the container.js script is found as well as declare a function without the arrow function. I've also tried to find the difference between this add button that has issues with the remove button and I can't see anything that I'm doing wrong in terms of typing or syntax.

Comment: [News] I just discovered that the issue was not the function to start with but not being able to assign any time of event to the button inside the if statement in the container class.

I've found answers to related issues here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68191332/i-cant-add-event-listener-to-a-object

Comment: [Update] Alright, so I solved my not being able to add events by finding the button from the parent element instead of finding the object itself. The arrow function helps me call the function from the globals hence I can create new objects by clicking the button. Now, the function is working recursively from bottom to top so I'm gonna find out what's going on with it. But, overall I feel I'm getting quite close to sort the whole thing out.

Comment: This is the code snippet in the container class that has helped with the issue:

`if(document.getElementById(id).className!='check-list'){
      document.getElementById(id).innerHTML+="<button id='"+id+"-add-button'>Issue</button>";
      document.getElementById(parentId).lastChild.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        this.child.addChild(id);});
`

Comment: [Update] There's not a recursion issues as I thought but an event bubbling triggering. https://dev.to/seanwelshbrown/using-stoppropagation-in-to-stop-event-bubbling-in-javascript-2g8d

Comment: Seems like a minimally reproducible example would help find the actual challenge presented here.  Note the example I presented actually bubbles the event up - from button to li to ul as you can see when you click said button - different question perhaps than the original however.

Comment: I found by accident that adding the event to the parent node triggers the event without any issue. Besides I could stop the event propagation with `stopPropagation()` function. I'm still unable to add the event but that problem is not related the this question so I'm gonna open a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like `addEventListener('click', (event) => {});` and then inside that reference the `event` properties like `target` re:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target

Super simple example: where now you DO have `this` as well

```js
// Make a list
const ul = document.createElement('ul');
document.body.appendChild(ul);

const li1 = document.createElement('li');
const li2 = document.createElement('li');
const btn = document.createElement('button');
btn.textContent = "Howdy Click me, I am not the li here but the UL triggers";
li2.appendChild(btn);
ul.appendChild(li1);
ul.appendChild(li2);

function hitMe(event) {
  // event.target refers to the clicked <li> element
  // This is different than event.currentTarget, which would refer to the parent <ul> in this context
  event.target.classList.toggle('blue-sky');
  event.currentTarget.classList.toggle("red-sky");
  console.log(this);
    console.log("target?:",this == event.target);
  console.log("currentTarget:?",this == event.currentTarget);
}

// Attach the listener to the list
// It will fire when each <li> is clicked
ul.addEventListener('click', hitMe, false);
```

```css
ul {
  border: solid 1px green;
}

li {
  border: solid 3px orange;
}

.blue-sky {
  border-color: skyblue;
}

.red-sky {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
  border-width: 4px;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Just be aware of what `this` IS here - I added a console log to show.  Try clicking the button, li and the ul (on the left)

Comment: Shultheiss I couldn't use your answer this time thanks anyways. Currently dealing with a recursion issue with the addChild function but I could add the event and trigger the function inside of it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions don't have their own bindings to `this` as methods, so `this` in your function refers to the `window`

```
  document.getElementById('session-add-button').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
      this.addChild(this.username+"-session"); // `this` refers to `Window`
    })
```

To fix just use an anonymous function, e.g.

```
  var username = this.username;
  document.getElementById('session-add-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
      this.addChild(username+"-session"); // `this` refers to your button
    })
```

Your other use of the arrow function works because you don't reference `this` in it.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the comment @Fraser, yeah this in this case refers to something else but I still wonder why I can't trigger an alert message inside of it in the container class for instance. –

Comment: @JuanJáuregui Because it throws an error and stops execution. Also it isn't a comment it is an answer.

Comment: Alright, I'll give it a try.  Good so thanks for the answer, still new here and I'm getting used to the platform

Comment: The add button works fine in the session script with the arrow function but if doesn't not with the anonymous function. The add button doesn't trigger anything with arrow function or the anonymous function.

Comment: @JuanJáuregui Then please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I've tried to deploy the project on GitHub pages but I don't know how cause I'm useing webpack. However, would you like to clone it instead? It's quite small. https://github.com/wavesinaroom/my_odin_project_todo-list . Let me know if this works for you otherwise I'll try another way

Comment: Oh just forgot to tell you that the example is in the stackoverflow remote branch of the project

Comment: You don't need to clone the projec @Fraser, I'm dealing with a recursion issue after finding out what the original problem was (checkout my update in the question comments). Thanks anyways for wanting to help!